# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln(1+\tan x)\,dx $

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln(1+\tan x)\,dx \\$$ 
 using $$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)\,dx \\$$

I got up to $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln(2)-\ln(1+\tan x)\,dx \\$ but I'm not sure how to integrate this

Thanks in advance

Comment: **If** $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1 + \tan x) dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(2) - \ln(1+\tan x) dx$$ as you write, then rearranging gives $$2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1 + \tan x) dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(2) \implies \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1 + \tan x) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(2)$$

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{1}{8} \pi  \log (2)$$

Comment: ahh I did not realise it was the same integral, thank you so much everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln(1+\tan x)dx= \int_0^{\pi/4} \left(\ln(2) - \ln(1+\tan x)\right)dx$$

$$= \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(2) dx - \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(1+ \tan x) dx$$

$$\Rightarrow 2\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln(1+ \tan x)dx = \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(2) dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln( 1 + \tan x)dx = \frac{\ln(2)}{2}\int_0^{\pi/4} dx = \boxed{\frac{\pi \ln(2)}{8}}$$